# What is the reason, sometimes the parameters in class does not defined in __init__ but added as instance variables?

Tags: python

Why does these attributes (commented) does not included in the **init** ?

```
class RRT(object):
  def __init__(self, start, stop, obstacle_list, rand_area):
    self.start = Node(start[0], start[1])
    self.stop = Node(stop[0], stop[1])
    self.min_rand = rand_area[0]        
    self.max_rand = rand_area[1]
    self.exapandDis = 1.0            # just like this one
    self.goalSampleRate = 0.05       # just like this one
    self.maxIter = 500               # just like this one
    self.obstacle_list = obstacle_list
```

Comment: Presumably, these values need a default value but change over the course of the object's execution. Can't say for sure without examples of how they are used.

Comment: Is this question why these variables are not in the `__init__` parameter list? If it makes sense to have alternate values for these variables then they should be part of the parameter list. E.G., `expandDis=1.0` in the params. But we can't say because we don't know other details of the class implementation.

Comment: you mean, whenever we want to have a default value for a attribute we can do so? am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever heard of constructor?
The `__init__` is a constructor in `Python`.

A constructor is used to initialized member variables of a class. It is not necessary for a constructor to initialize each and every variable.

Sometimes, we want a constructor to initialize variables, which aren't passed in as parameters, with some default values.

It is not necessary for a construtor to only intialize the variables which are passed to it!

Thus, your code will initialize: `exapandDis, goalSampleRate, maxIter` with default values `1.0, 0.05, 500`

Comment: got it, thank you. so what is the logic behind that? I mean how can I know this attribute should be add to __init__ when not ??

Comment: @KamyarOthman If you want user to determine the value, put it in parameter. If it is some default value, just set it

Comment: @KamyarOthman it depends upon the programmer/coder. Whether s/he wants some values to be initialised as mentioned in parameters or set it as default values.

Answer (score 0):

You can give parameters default values. These are called "keyword arguments".

```
class RRT(object):
  def __init__(self, start, stop, obstacle_list, rand_area,
        exapandDis=1.0, goalSampleRate=.05, maxIter=500):
    self.start = Node(start[0], start[1])
    self.stop = Node(stop[0], stop[1])
    self.min_rand = rand_area[0]        
    self.max_rand = rand_area[1]
    self.exapandDis = expandDis                # just like this one
    self.goalSampleRate = goalSampleRate       # just like this one
    self.maxIter = maxIter                     # just like this one
    self.obstacle_list = obstacle_list
```

Now, when someone creates an instance of the class, they must supply the positional arguments `start, stop, obstacle_list, rand_area` but the others are optional. For instance, if you want to keep defaults expandDis and goalSapleRate but want a different maxIter, you would do

```
RRT(1, 100, [], 66, maxIter=1000)
```